# asp.net button click not working properly

Tags: asp.net, button

```
protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
    }
```

im using this code but on clicking button code is breaking saing this in picture

[image]

Comment: The error says that you are trying to access `http://localhost:7168/login/` but the page can not be found. Do you have code in home.aspx that redirects to `/login/`? And does `/login/` exist?

Comment: try "../home.aspx"

Comment: What's your routing?

Comment: routing meaning  ?

Comment: home.aspx does not redirect to login

Comment: but both pages exist in a same project

Comment: Can you post photo of your project folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
{
    Response.Redirect("~/home.aspx");
}
```

u can try using the following to go back to root.

```
{
    Response.Redirect("~/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Its unable to find your home.aspx page(If you have renamed your page).
2.Check Your .aspx page name properly(Weather home.aspx is there or not).
3.If it is Home.aspx and you are giving home.aspx then it will give the error.
```

It may be

```
 Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
```

Or you can try

```
Server.Transfer("Home.aspx");
```